# How to access a file with a relative path in a node module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, require

I am building an app in node.js + express and I'm getting a file directory error.

I have a test file called `ajax.js` in my `/app/lib/tests` folder. My `app.js` file is in my root `/app` directory. Here is a snippet of my app.js file that is giving me trouble:

```
https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./security/keys/localhost.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./security/keys/localhost.crt')
}, app).listen(https_port);
```

In my `ajax.js` file I require my app.js file:

```
var server = require('../../app');
```

The problem with this is it's givng me this error:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './security/keys/localhost.key'` which tells me the file directories are not lining up properly. My `ajax.js` file works if I change

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './security/keys/localhost.key'`

to

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../../security/keys/localhost.key'`

However, this would break my app overall.

Is there a way I can have the file directory from app.js propogate over to ajax.js?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the absolute path of this file `./security/keys/localhost.key` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `require.resolve()` to resolve the path in the required module's context and use the resolved path to access the file system:

```
https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync(require.resolve('./security/keys/localhost.key')),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(require.resolve('./security/keys/localhost.crt'))
}, app).listen(https_port);
```